# How to use Partials with Nustache in c# application?

Tags: c#, mustache

I have a windows application using Nustache. I can iterate an object or array using Nustache, But how to do partial Enumeration using Nustache?

[Check this link](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/)

check sample 11.

```
var data = { depts: [
{   name: "Engineering",
    employees: [
        {firstName: "Christophe", lastName: "Coenraets"},
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"}]
},
{   name: "Sales",
    employees: [
        {firstName: "Paula", lastName: "Taylor"},
        {firstName: "Lisa", lastName: "Jones"}]
}]     };

 var tpl = "{{#depts}}<h1>{{name}}</h1>" +
          "<ul>{{#employees}}{{>employee}}{{/employees}}</ul>{{/depts}}";

var partials = {employee:"<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>"};
var html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data, partials);
$('#sampleArea').html(html);
```

How to achieve the same in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify tpl as shown below!

```
var tpl = "{{employee}}<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>{{/employee}}{{#depts}}<h1>{{name}}</h1>" +
      "<ul>{{#employees}}{{>employee}}{{/employees}}</ul>{{/depts}}";
```

Then pass your object array. it will fetch properly.!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I found that there is a way to do what you are asking. 
Nustache allows the creation of a template or partial inline using the < symbol so {{>employee}}your partial template here {{/employee}} would be your partial and then when you want to reference it simply use the > symbol, ex: {{>employee}}

From the readme.txt file

```
64      {{<foo}}This is the foo template.{{/foo}}
65      The above doesn't get rendered until it's included
66      like this:
67      {{>foo}}
```

so your new code in nustache would be:

```
    string tpl = "{{<employee}}<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>{{/employee}}" +
"{{#depts}}<h1>{{name}}</h1><ul>{{#employees}}{{>employee}}{{/employees}}</ul>{{/depts}}";

    string html = Nustache.Core.Render.StringToString(tpl, data);
```

using this technique allows recursive template rendering, the following will render and heirarchy of departments and employees

```
{{<employee}}<li>{{firstname}} {{lastname}}{{>dept}}</li>{{/employee}}
{{<dept}}   
    <ul>                            
        <li >
            <span >{{name}}</span>                  
            {{#employees}}                          
                {{>employee}}
            {{/children}}           
        </li>                       
    </ul>
{{/dept}}{{>dept}}
```